# I keep getting a error when I call this index even if I change the indexes

Tags: python

I'm still a beginner how do I get rid of this error in my code, I have to print all the names and surnames in a text file this is my code

```
with open("DOB.txt", "r+", encoding="cp1252") as file:
    content = file.read().split("\n")
    
    for line in content:
        names = line.split() 
        print(names[0] + " " + names[1])
```

it prints out all the names and surnames but still gives the error

```
Kelly Gardner
Cristina Ortega
Guy Carr
Geneva Martinez
Ricardo Howell
Bernadette Rios
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\27711\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\Bootcamp\compulsary_task.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(names[0] + " " + names[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried removing the \n in the split ontop but it still gives me a error after it prints the names and surnames

Comment: It probably hits a line where only one name exists,  try `print(names)` first and see what it's trying to split

Comment: Exactly what it says, you probably don't have a surname on that line which causes this error.

Comment: Can you show the file??

Comment: open the file `DOB.txt`. Look for `Bernadette Rios` - the line after has 1 or zero fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defensive code below

```
with open("DOB.txt", "r+", encoding="cp1252") as file:
    content = file.read().split("\n")
    
    for line in content:
        names = line.split() 
        if len(names) >= 2: 
          print(names[0] + " " + names[1])
        else:
          print(f'Not enough fields: {names}')
```

Answer (score 1):

just put it after for loop starts

```
if line!='':
    names = line.split() 
    print(names[0] + " " + names[1])
```

The problem is /n at the end and you are trying to go through that

Also its possible the name has only one element or is empty, and you trying to access it. so you should just insert an If statement either after for loop starts or after this "names = line.split()".

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is due to you attempting to pull a value that is not there.

The simplest way to solve this is with a try except

```
for line in content:
    try:
        names = line.split() 
        print(names[0] + " " + names[1])
    except IndexError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: instead of print(e) you can use the outcome you want instead

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that one of the lines doesn't have two names. Proabably one of the lines has only one name. As a result `split()` has only one word in it and hence names[1] is out of range error